# SnowFlake Datawarehouse : 'show tables' & create table using spark

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 questions w.r.t spark and Snowflake datawarehouse.

1) Is there any way to query/create snowflake tables like hive/spark(either new or old versions of spark)

```
val hive_tables=hiveContext.sql("show tables").foreach(println)
```

2) `hiveContext.sql("create table....")`

first question is about knowing what tables are present for that particular user for the particular role. The reason why I am asking question is via web ui of snowflake I am able to query the table but through spark I am not able to query

```
Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
Object 'mytable' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should double check things like database/schema/role in your JDBC connection settings. If you don't see a table via JDBC, one of these might be the culprit.

You can validate the current settings by running e.g. `show roles`, `show schemas` and `show databases` on the established JDBC connection.

In general, I highly recommend using Spark-Snowflake connector for communicating with Snowflake from Spark. It also provides `Utils.runQuery()` for running simple queries like DDL.